# Get logo using WP REST API

Tags: html, angularjs, json, wordpress

I am trying to get the logo I set in wordpress using json but I can't find it anywhere, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Comment: Well I haven't tried much since I can't find the logo in the results json is giving me. I can find the picture however under media but that's not really a good way to display the logo.

Comment: I suppose that if it would be available it could be on the root endpoint ( /wp-json ), but I don't see it. Perhaps it's not possible in the current version

Comment: Hmm yeah that's what I am afraid of, do you happen to know any other way to get the logo from wordpress in a html file?